# Firebase Auth via Facebook and Google what with Privacy Policy?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-authentication, facebook-authentication, privacy-policy

I want to develop simple database backend with Firebase Realtime Database to my Android app.
I want to auth users via Firebase Auth (Facebook and Google).
Do I need to write Privacy Policy ? 
I guess the answer is yes, so is there any pre-made Privacy Policy for this (I store only information provided by this Auth system: displayName, email, imgUri) ?